# How do i get the full path of a file

Tags: php, path, server

Hello I recently made a private system for creating files on a server when I'm logged in, I also wanted that it checks if an file exist, i do this with the `file_exist()` function.

The problem is file exist needs the full path like `C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php` that works but just `\index.php` does not works, and most of the times you don't get that path from your webhost.

Is there a way to get the full server path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `realpath(dirname(__FILE__));`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use PHP Magic Constant `__FILE__`.

```
$fileName = __FILE__;
var_dump($fileName);
```

**Output**

```
string 'C:\wamp\www\so\x.php' (length=20)
```